# How can I collect a photo submitted by a user?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How can I collect a photo submitted by a user and send it in an embed? I'm using discord.js v13.

I've got the following code but `img` is not an image URL:

```js
interaction.reply({ content: 'Envia alguna imagen...' }).then(async () => {
  const atch_filter = (m) => !!m.attachments || m.startsWith('https');
  const collected = await interaction.channel.awaitMessages({
    filter: atch_filter,
    max: 1,
  });
  var img = collected.first().url;

  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Foto recibida')
    .setImage(img)
    .setColor('BLUE');

  interaction.editReply({ content: 'Listo!', embeds: [embed] });
});
```

Comment: You are using the `Message` url (`collected` is a `Collection` of `Message`s and you are getting the first `Message` and accessing the URL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`awaitMessages`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) returns a collection of messages. Even if it's a single message it's still in a collection. As you set up your filter correctly, the collected message will be `collected.first()`.

Messages have an [`attachments`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments) property, a collection of attachments in the message, so the image will be the first item in the collection; `collected.first().attachments.first()`. To grab the URL you can use either its [`url`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment?scrollTo=url) property:

```js
const atch_filter = (m) => !!m.attachments || m.startsWith('https');
const collected = await interaction.channel.awaitMessages({
  filter: atch_filter,
  max: 1,
});
const img = collected.first().attachments.first().url;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's what you can try defining image as

```
let image = collected.attachments.first() ? message.attachments.first().proxyURL : null
```